# Displaying ivreg2 first stage statistics using estout in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to add first stage statistics from the `ivreg2` command, namely the A-P F stat, into the output for the first stage results using `estout`.  I am aware that these statistics are stored in the `e(first)` matrix from the second stage results, but I am having trouble figuring out how to present those statistics in the first stage results.  I have tried the following and neither works:

```
ivreg2 y `included' (q=z), first ffirst savefirst savefprefix(first_)
estimates store m1
estadd matrix first=first: first_q
estimates restore first_q
```

and then tried including `APF` as a statistic in `estout` and it doesn't work.  I have also tried adding the lines:

```
matrix first=e(first)
estadd scalar APF=first[7,1]
```

and that also doesn't work.  I also tried writing a new `_estadd_apf.ado` subcommand and couldn't get that to work, and tried using the `myel[#]` syntax described in the `estout` help file and that does not work either. (It seems that including brackets anywhere in the `stats()` option results in an error.)  I also tried the `aux()` option in the `esttab` wrapper and that didn't work.

When I type `matrix list first` I can see the correct APF value, but it is stored in a matrix rather than a scalar and `estout` will not include it in the table, the cells are just blank.  I also tried just defining a local scalar without using `estadd`, and that too doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The `myel[#]` option is for `cells()`, not `stats()`. `stats()` only takes scalars.

Answer (score 5):

Am I missing something? `estadd scalar` seems to work in this case.

```
clear
set more off
use http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/hayashi/griliches76.dta // example from the help file
xi i.year
ivreg2 lw s expr tenure rns smsa _I* (iq=med kww age mrt), small first ffirst savefirst savefprefix(first_)
mat first=e(first)
estadd scalar APF=first[7,1]
estout, c(b) stats(APF)
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure why this didn't work for me the first time, but thanks.  I have literally the exact same lines of code above in my question.  Anyway, this works.  To get the first stage just need to tweak the above code as: 
        `estadd scalar APF=first[7,1]: first_iq` ;
        `est restore first_iq` ;
        `estout, c(b) stats(APF)` ;